# Mac OS X: Listen to Bluetooth MONO Audio?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

Simple question:  With OS X (or some 3rd party software), can I listen to audio from my apps like Safari and iTunes through a bluetooth headset?  I'm not talking about a Stereo A2DP set, but rather a REGULAR OLD bluetooth headset for mobile phones (which I think uses the "HSP" bluetooth profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I've done this. Just use the Bluetooth Setup Assistant to pair the headset as you normally would, and the headset will appear as an option in the "Output" tab of the "Sound" section of System Preferences (as well as the "Input" tab - I presume it has a microphone).

Comment: I use RogueAmoeba's SoundSource app to route some, or all, of my Mac's audio signals to my BT Plantronics headset (which is mono). After I turn on the headset it shows up in SoundSource as an available output device and I can route "Output" and/or "System" sounds to the headset or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is natively possible, but I can't help you with how (at least exactly). This happened to me accidentally when I was trying to use my A2DP headset but instead connected the handsfree profile. If I remember correctly, when you pair your headset, you should see the BT devices added and then you can change them in system preferences -> sound.